# Text overflowing invisibly behind left margin after using "vertical-lr" mode and rotating it 90 degrees

Tags: html, css, text

I made a simple div and rotated the text -90 degrees after using the `vertical-lr` writing mode. But the text overflows invisibly behind the left margin. But when I add a margin on the div, it gets fixed.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9suU.png)

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><div>Simple div</div><div style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(-90deg);">Rotated text goes here </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Please let me know, if you need this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div><div>Simple div</div><div style="writing-mode: vertical-lr; transform: rotate(90deg);     transform-origin: bottom left;">Rotated text goes here </div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nope, i dont want it to be upside down,

Comment: what you actually want, show some graphical representation